# how to use offical google translate api on local runtime via python

Tags: python, google-api, google-translate

after reading the offical google translate api document, it provide us with the following sample code:

```
from google.cloud import translate
def translate_text(text="Hello, world!", project_id="weighty-site-333613"):

    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient().from_service_account_json('key.json')
    location = "global"
    parent = f"projects/{project_id}/locations/{location}"
    response = client.translate_text(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "contents": [text],
            "mime_type": "text/plain",
            "source_language_code": "en-US",
            "target_language_code": "zh-CN",
        }
    )

    for translation in response.translations:
        print("Translated text: {}".format(translation.translated_text))
translate_text()
```

These code worked properly on google cloud terminal.
However, even if i put the "key.json" file in the same folder, an error like this is shown:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.6 /Users/jiajunmao/Documents/GitHub/translator_of_excel/google_trans.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jiajunmao/Documents/GitHub/translator_of_excel/google_trans.py", line 37, in <module>
    translate_text()
  File "/Users/jiajunmao/Documents/GitHub/translator_of_excel/google_trans.py", line 22, in translate_text
    client = translate.TranslationServiceClient().from_service_account_json('key.json')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v3/services/translation_service/client.py", line 354, in __init__
    always_use_jwt_access=True,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v3/services/translation_service/transports/grpc.py", line 158, in __init__
    always_use_jwt_access=always_use_jwt_access,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/translate_v3/services/translation_service/transports/base.py", line 110, in __init__
    **scopes_kwargs, quota_project_id=quota_project_id
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 488, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started

Process finished with exit code 1
```

can someone tell me what should i do at this step? thank you so much

Comment: Do you have service account file in the project?

Answer (score 1):

You need service account json file with correct permissions from GCP under IAM & Service Accounts.

Then you need to implement command,

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = "/path/to/your/service_account.json"
```

Comment: May I know where should I put this one?

Comment: Recommended is in root, but because you need to point full path, you can place it anywhere in the project.